# Do I need to know assembler in order to be able to disassemble an executable?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Do I need to know assembler in order to be able to disassemble an executable?
and understand what's the program doing? Thank you.

Comment: What CPU or Instruction Set Architecture are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to know assembler in order to be able to disassemble an executable?

No. All you need is a disassembler / debugger.

> and understand what's the program doing?

Yes. Once the disassembler has produced the disassembly, you should know how to read the disassembly and what the various instructions are doing. You should also have an understanding on the architecture of your CPU, like which registers exist, what the memory model is, which special function registers exist etc. You should also have a basic understanding of the operating system your executable is running on, in order to understand certain sub routine calls or calls into the (protected) operating system layer.

All this is very system specific - a good starting point usually is the data sheet / manual of your concrete CPU which usually contains sections about the architecture and a reference section describing the instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

There is some workaround for reading disassembled programs. In the case when you using IDA disassembler, you can apply HexRays plug-in that can build C-style code from the raw assembly captured previously (Just open the code of the function that you interested in and press F5). It can be useful if you didn't know the assembler at all, but according to my experience HexRay isn't perfect and sometimes can produce incorrect C-style code and sometimes fails to generate code at all. So, due to this I use it only as an auxilary tool in the code analysis. But if you didn't know assembler at all, you can try to use it.